# cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const container<T>' to 'container<T> &'

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting following `STL compilation error` in the following code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class container {
public:
  container(std::string in_key="") {
    m_element_index = 0;
  }
  ~container() {
  }
  // Returns the numbers of elements in the container
  int size() {
    return m_element_index;
  }
  // Assignment operator
  // Assigns a copy of container x as the new content for the container object.
  container& operator= (const container& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
      for ( int idx = 0; idx < other.size(); idx++) {
      }
    }
    return *this;
  }
private:
  int m_element_index;
};

int main ( int argc, char** argv) {
  container<int> v1("my_container");
  container<int> v2("copy_cont");
  v2 = v1;
}
```

Getting error for following line

`for ( int idx = 0; idx < other.size(); idx++) {`

Error is

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>e:\avinash\test\test\test.cpp(20): error C2662: 'container<T>::size' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const container<T>' to 'container<T> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
1>          e:\avinash\test\test\test.cpp(18) : while compiling class template member function 'container<T> &container<T>::operator =(const container<T> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          e:\avinash\test\test\test.cpp(30) : see reference to class template instantiation 'container<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
  int size() {
    return m_element_index;
  }
```

to this:

```
  int size() const {
    return m_element_index;
  }
```

To tell the compiler that you want it to allow `size()` to be called on a `const` instance.

Answer (score 4):

Here you are passing a const object to the assignment operator:

```
container& operator= (const container& other) {
    <...>
}
```

However, inside of the operator, you are calling the `other`'s `size()` function:

```
for ( int idx = 0; idx < other.size(); idx++)
```

To make it availible for using with a `const` object, the function itself must be declared as `const`:

```
int size() const {
    return m_element_index;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `size()` as a `const` method:

```
int size() const {
    return m_element_index;
}
```

because in your assignment operator

```
container& operator= (const container& other) { .... }
```

you are calling `other.size()`, and `other` is a `reference-to-const`, meaning you can only call const methods on it.